# Unix command to copy file from remote server to a terminal shell

Tags: rsync

I am using the terminal shell, and I’m finding it difficult to copy a file from my school remote server to my local machine.
I need to use this file to start my final project.
I used this command but it’s giving an error message.

```
rsync -avx eve.kean.edu:/tmp/directory/hosts.
```

The file name is `hosts` and my professor copied it into the `/tmp/`directory; my school remote name is `eve.kean.edu` and my user name is `nwodo@eve`.  Below is what I’m getting with the command.

Answer (score 1):

Without the error message, it's hard to answer the question. But from the command you supplied, one can guess that you probably forgot to specify the destination on your local machine. So assuming you want to copy the file `/tmp/directory/hosts` from `eve.kean.edu` (the remote side) to the current directory on you local machine, you have to add `.` (white space + dot) to your command, like this:

```
$ rsync -avx eve.kean.edu:/tmp/directory/hosts .                    
receiving incremental file list
hosts

sent 43 bytes  received 23,300 bytes  4,244.18 bytes/sec
total size is 23,191  speedup is 0.99
```

more info can be found in the manual page `man rsync` ([online version](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/rsync.1.html))